# How to open blob link use webview of android?

Tags: android, webview

I want to display video in android app.

The link of video is blob link so that i think i need use webview to display it.

How to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WebView support loading HTML data from string](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). So following code is possible.

```
 String videoBlobLinkUrl = "data:video/mp4;base64,[video base64-encoded data ..]";
 String videoBlobMime = "video/mp4";

 String videoHtml = "<html><body><video><source type=\""+videoBlobMime+"\" src=\""+ videoBlobLinkUrl +"\"></video></body></html>";
 webview.loadData(videoHtml, "text/html", null);
```